# Properly center math mode with indices within TikZ nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

When making a graph in TikZ where the labels of some nodes have indices and the labels of others do not, there is a very ugly effect where TikZ tries to center the *entire* label instead of the baseline, because each node is assigned its own baseline.

You can see what I mean in the following example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
Ti\textit{k}Z gives each node its own baseline for text:
 \begin{center}
   \tikz{
     \node (y1) at (1,.8) {}; \node (y2) at (1,-.8) {};
     \node (y3) at (2,.8) {}; \node (y4) at (2,-.8) {};

     \node[draw, circle, minimum size=24pt] (1) at (1,0) {\(v\)};
     \node[draw, circle, minimum size=24pt] (2) at (2,0) {\(v_{1}\)};
   }
   \tikz{
     \node (a) at (0,0) {}; \node (b) at (3,0) {};
     \node (y1) at (1,.8) {}; \node (y2) at (1,-.8) {};
     \node (y3) at (2,.8) {}; \node (y4) at (2,-.8) {};
     \path[draw=red] (a) to (b);
     \path[draw=red] (y1) to (y2);
     \path[draw=red] (y3) to (y4);

     \node[draw, circle, minimum size=24pt] (1) at (1,0) {\(v\)};
     \node[draw, circle, minimum size=24pt] (2) at (2,0) {\(v_{1}\)};
   }
 \end{center}
 The effect is more obvious with squares:
 \begin{center}
   \tikz{
     \node (y1) at (1,.8) {}; \node (y2) at (1,-.8) {};
     \node (y3) at (2,.8) {}; \node (y4) at (2,-.8) {};

     \node[draw, circle, minimum size=24pt] (1) at (1,0) {\(\square\)};
     \node[draw, circle, minimum size=24pt] (2) at (2,0) {\(\square_{1}\)};
   }
   \tikz{
     \node (a) at (0,0) {}; \node (b) at (3,0) {};
     \node (y1) at (1,.8) {}; \node (y2) at (1,-.8) {};
     \node (y3) at (2,.8) {}; \node (y4) at (2,-.8) {};
     \path[draw=red] (a) to (b);
     \path[draw=red] (y1) to (y2);
     \path[draw=red] (y3) to (y4);

     \node[draw, circle, minimum size=24pt] (1) at (1,0) {\(\square\)};
     \node[draw, circle, minimum size=24pt] (2) at (2,0) {\(\square_{1}\)};

   }
 \end{center}
 Math mode instead uses the same baseline:
  \begin{center}
   \tikz{
     \node (a) at (0,0) {}; \node (b) at (4,0) {};
     \path[draw=red] (a) to (b);

     \node[draw, circle] (1) at (2,0) {\(\square = \square_{1}\)};
   }
 \end{center}  
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

What I would like instead would be for both vertices to have the "v" at the same position, like they are in math mode, because otherwise it looks quite odd when both vertices appear side by side in a graph.

Is there a way to do this without fudging with `\phantom` letters and whatnot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `anchor=mid` or `anchor=base` in the node options. Here is the result with the former:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
Ti\textit{k}Z gives each node its own baseline for text:
 \begin{center}
   \tikz{
     \node (y1) at (1,.8) {}; \node (y2) at (1,-.8) {};
     \node (y3) at (2,.8) {}; \node (y4) at (2,-.8) {};

     \node[draw, circle, minimum size=24pt, anchor=mid] (1) at (1,0) {\(v\)};
     \node[draw, circle, minimum size=24pt, anchor=mid] (2) at (2,0) {\(v_{1}\)};
   }
   \tikz{
     \node (a) at (0,0) {}; \node (b) at (3,0) {};
     \node (y1) at (1,.8) {}; \node (y2) at (1,-.8) {};
     \node (y3) at (2,.8) {}; \node (y4) at (2,-.8) {};
     \path[draw=red] (a) to (b);
     \path[draw=red] (y1) to (y2);
     \path[draw=red] (y3) to (y4);

     \node[draw, circle, minimum size=24pt, anchor=mid] (1) at (1,0) {\(v\)};
     \node[draw, circle, minimum size=24pt, anchor=mid] (2) at (2,0) {\(v_{1}\)};
   }
 \end{center}
 The effect is more obvious with squares:
 \begin{center}
   \tikz{
     \node (y1) at (1,.8) {}; \node (y2) at (1,-.8) {};
     \node (y3) at (2,.8) {}; \node (y4) at (2,-.8) {};

     \node[draw, circle, minimum size=24pt, anchor=mid] (1) at (1,0) {\(\square\)};
     \node[draw, circle, minimum size=24pt, anchor=mid] (2) at (2,0) {\(\square_{1}\)};
   }
   \tikz{
     \node (a) at (0,0) {}; \node (b) at (3,0) {};
     \node (y1) at (1,.8) {}; \node (y2) at (1,-.8) {};
     \node (y3) at (2,.8) {}; \node (y4) at (2,-.8) {};
     \path[draw=red] (a) to (b);
     \path[draw=red] (y1) to (y2);
     \path[draw=red] (y3) to (y4);

     \node[draw, circle, minimum size=24pt, anchor=mid] (1) at (1,0) {\(\square\)};
     \node[draw, circle, minimum size=24pt, anchor=mid] (2) at (2,0) {\(\square_{1}\)};

   }
 \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `anchor=base`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for! Is there a similar trick for the horizontal shift of the content?

Comment: For horizontal placement, I don't see any other option than making TeX believe both “things” have the same width (using `\phantom` and/or `\makebox` tricks).

Comment: Sadly, the `graphdrawing` library seems to ignore this option. A MWE does not fit in a comment, but essentially, as soon as I use `graphdrawing` and pass `anchor=mid` to the two vertices, they stay as before, i.e. wrong.